# Why do I get this cv2.error when I set the net.forward output?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, yolo

I'm doing some machine learning object detection with cv2 and I always get a cv2.error:

> OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\layers\convolution_layer.cpp:1114: error: (-215:Assertion failed) inputs[0].size[1] % blobs[0].size[1] == 0 in function 'cv::dnn::ConvolutionLayerImpl::forward'

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNet("yolov3.weights","yolov3.cfg")

layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
output_layers = [layer_names[i[0]-1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]

img = op('null1').numpyArray(delayed=True)
#print(img.dtype)#float32

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
gray = (gray *255).astype(np.uint8)
#print(gray.dtype)#uint8

blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img,1/255,(416,416),(0,0,0),swapRB=True,crop=False)

net.setInput(blob)

out = net.forward(output_layers)#!!! HERE OCCURS MY ERROR
```

Anyone a suggestion what causes this error?
Do I have to change the pixelformat?

Comment: What is OpenCV version?

Comment: open cv version 3.2

Answer (score 0):

You should change `1/255` to be `1.0/255` so that it doesn't be zero.

Also I think this line should be like this

```
output_layers=[]
for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers():
    output_layers.append(layer_names[i[0]-1])
```

Comment: Thanks for the respond but with that I actually get the same error :/

Answer (score 0):

#you should add these 2 lines of code:

```
net.setPreferableBackend(cv.dnn.DNN_BACKEND_OPENCV)
net.setPreferableTarget(cv2.dnn.DNN_TARGET_CPU)
```

#below this:

```
net = cv.dnn.readNetFromDarknet('yolov3.cfg', 'yolov3.weights')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
outputNames = [layerNames[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
```